# Why is this SQL query with subquery very slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select *
from transaction_batch
where id IN
(
    select MAX(id) as id
    from transaction_batch
    where status_id IN (1,2)
    group by status_id
);
```

The inner query runs very fast (less than 0.1 seconds) to get two ID's, one for status 1, one for status 2, then it selects based on primary key so it is indexed. The explain query says that it's searching 135k rows using where only, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is so slow.

Comment: MySQL is pretty dumb about optimizing sub-queries, that's why it's slow. The only way to improve it is to re-write it as a JOIN (as shown by RedFilter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select b.*
from transaction_batch b
inner join (
    select max(id) as id
    from transaction_batch
    where status_id in (1, 2)
    group by status_id
) bm on b.id = bm.id
```

Comment: Though I agree that the op should try this query, it doesn't answer op's question at all

Comment: Thanks, this actually makes a lot of sense (although it does not answer the question directly, I get why it works better).

Comment: @Lamak My apologies for not having an explanation of the why. I don't understand MySQL internals. All I can do is show the way that I have found is faster empirically. As always, EXPLAIN is your friend here.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 20):

The inner query is run seperatly for every row of your table over and over again.

As there is no reference to the outer query in the inner query, I suggest you split those two queries and just insert the results of the inner query in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This actually answers the question, Even though that query takes .1s as the OP points out, you are multiplying that by EVERY row returned. If you return 100,000 rows, you just got 10,000s (167m) query on your hands.

Comment: Much better answer as to 'WHY' using a subquery is slow.

Comment: This is not correct, it's due to the planner not being able to plan accurately. You can prove that to yourself by creating a temporary table using "WITH" instead, and then joining to that. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114361/47508 for context

Answer (score 0):

my first post here.. sorry about the lack of formatting

I had a performance problem shown below:

90sec: `WHERE [Column] LIKE (Select [Value] From [Table])`   //Dynamic, slow

1sec:  `WHERE [Column] LIKE ('A','B','C')`                   //Hardcoded, fast

1sec:  `WHERE @CSV like CONCAT('%',[Column],'%')`            //Solution, below

I had tried joining rather than subquerying.

I had also tried a hardcoded CTE.

I had lastly tried a temp table.

None of these standard options worked, and I was not willing to dosp_execute option.

The only solution that worked as:

```
DECLARE @CSV nvarchar(max) = Select STRING_AGG([Value],',') From [Table];

// This yields @CSV = 'A,B,C'

...

WHERE @CSV LIKE CONCAT('%',[Column],'%')
```

Comment: Hi Donovan - Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to not post your own question as the answer to someone else's open Question, as you will likely not get noticed for your own help (Instead create a new Question so that we all see it and can assist you directly)