# MySQL sub query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am developing a LMS in which i have develop an inquiry management system.
the system was working well when database has a few entries
the notification system is based on two tables one is the inquiry information table and the other one has the next follow up date and time including comments

[image]

Here is the inquiry table

[image]

And this one for inquiry follow up,

and this is the query that i am using to get all the pending inquiries where the date is less than and equal to current date

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM enquiry_follows AS t1
WHERE t1.dfollow = (   SELECT MAX(t2.dfollow)
                       FROM enquiry_follows AS t2
                       WHERE (t2.enquiryid = t1.enquiryid)
                       AND NOW () >= t2.dfollow
                       AND status = 'unseen'
                       AND EXISTS (   SELECT t3.*
                                      FROM inquiries AS t3
                                      WHERE t2.enquiryid = t3.id
                                      AND status = 'pending'
                                      AND campus = '".$_SESSION['campus']."'))
ORDER BY t1.dfollow DESC;
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Create index in each column you gonna equal to something. like enquiryid (both tables) and dfollow

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: maybe you can also use a trigger to update a field  when status change. In this way maybe you can also simplify you query

Comment: The innermost subquery can be turned into an inner join with the "outer" subquery. If you provide us with an environment (see: sqlfiddle.com), we can help more. Why is it slow for you? All the subqueries are executed _per row_ of their outer select part, welcome to MySQL. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883975/357403